# Where are the GA release artifacts akka-http & akka-streams 1.0?

Tags: maven, akka, spray, akka-http

On 15 July 2015 http://akka.io/news/2015/07/15/akka-streams-1.0-released.html said that Akka Streams & Akka Http have be released at version 1.0, but I don't see them in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.typesafe.akka%22%20a%3A%22akka-http%22) or in the [Typesafe repo](http://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/maven-releases/com/typesafe/akka/).  There only appear to be the "-experimental" artifacts.

Where are the 1.0 non-experimental releases hosted?

Answer (score 4):

You are probably looking for [`akka-stream-experimental_2.10`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-stream-experimental_2.10/1.0) in the Maven central repository.

It does have "experimental" in its name but it was released on the 15 July 2015, same date as the news post, so I am guessing it is the correct one.